# Error when require('react-native-xmpp') on android project

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm

I tried to install XMPP module in react native project
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-xmpp

but after I use

```
var XMPP = require('react-native-xmpp');
```

it was return error

```
Cannot read property 'PLAIN' of undefined

Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

here is my react native versions

```
react-native: 0.57.1
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

I didn't find where is this error occur 
please help

here is screenshots of configuration

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: you have tested it on! android or ios?

Comment: have you setup the  'react native link' and also checked the android MyAPPlication.java file!

Comment: android yes of course i use `react-native link react-native-xmpp`

Comment: I think there have issue with versions of react native

Comment: can you post your MyApplication.java class here please

Comment: and it should be rnpm link react-native-xmpp, as they have mentioned ! in the installation docs

Comment: i edited question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185780/discussion-between-rizwan-atta-and-code-kadiya).

Comment: without xmpp app was working fine?

Comment: yes it is working fine after remove xmpp

Comment: did you try it on different android phones! because i just followed the basic steps and then ran gradle clean and app got run fine!

Comment: it is not a problem with gradle there is something wrong with code implementation

Comment: you have filed the issue on React Native FrameWork github repo! you should make an issue on XMPP repo about this issue! they can help you with it! more

Comment: yes that is great idea, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185886/discussion-between-rizwan-atta-and-code-kadiya).

Answer (score 1):

you have the implementation of xmpp in your **build.gradle** dependencies! **redundant**

means its written twice
first remove that

and then go to

> cd android

using android gradlew clean it!

> cd ./gradlew && clean

after that run the react-native run-android

it should get you going with that error! now next depends upon how you are configuring XMPP